# Groovy - GString being used as key versus String as key, subscript notation versus put method

Tags: groovy, gstring

In the [groovy documentation](http://www.groovy-lang.org/single-page-documentation.html), it mentions that using a GString for a key is bad:

```
def key = 'some key'
def map = [:]
def gstringKey = "${key.toUpperCase()}"
map.put(gstringKey,'value')
assert map.get('SOME KEY') == null
```

However, simply changing the put() method to use subscript notation:

```
def key = 'some key'
def map = [:]
def gstringKey = "${key.toUpperCase()}"
map[gstringKey] = 'value' // here
assert map.get('SOME KEY') == null
```

is enough to cause the assert to fail. How are the semantics any different between using [] and the put() method? Does subscript notation have some sort of implicit cast to String maybe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Does the subscript notation have an implicit cast to String?*

Basically, yes.

The statement `a[b] = c` is equivalent to calling the `a.putAt(b, c)` method, as per the Groovy [operator overloading](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#Operator-Overloading) rules.

The specific signature of the [`putAt` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#putAt(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) is `void putAt(String property, Object newValue)`, which means that if `b` is a Groovy String, it will first be converted to a String using its `toString()` method.

Ultimately, the `putAt` method will call `Map.put` using the `String` value as the key.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with using a `GString` as a map key with subscript notation. The conversions to a `String` is probably what one would want anyway. The Groovy documentation should instead warn against using the `get` and `put` methods of `Map`.